# Update controls with same parent during design time

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

So i created a new control with a label and an edit (just like the standard TLabelEdit).

The controls inherits from TCustomEdit.

The label gets the same parent by overriding the `SetParent` method.

When i now move the control during design time it will only move the "edit part" of the control and leave the label on its original position like in this video i made:

http://gfycat.com/QuarrelsomeWildHammerkop

The label "Birthday" stays on the same position while moving the control around.

Is there a way to update both positions in the desinger while dragging / moving the control around?

I logged the window messages using Spy++ but it doesn't fire any messages while moving around.

Even adding a timer and trying to adjust the label size ever 20ms isn't working...

Comment: `TLabeledEdit` does the same thing, despite overriding the Edit's virtual `SetBounds()` method, and the Label's virtual `AdjustBounds()` method. What it doesn't do is handle the [`WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632653.aspx) message. Have you tried that yet?

Comment: WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING gets fired before dragging and after but sadly not during. As i wrote i checkd the messages and it seems none get fired during movement.

Comment: Try overriding the virtual `AdjustSize()` method to position your label, and then override `SetBounds()` and `Resize()` to call `AdjustSize()`. Here is an example: [Delphi - Compound Components](http://mc-computing.com/languages/delphi/ComponentCompound.html).

Comment: Sadly none of these get called while moving

Comment: How does `TLabeledEdit` behaves (I do not have Delphi 10 to test)? 
"I logged the window messages using Spy++..."  it is possible (and even logical IMO) that the actual Edit window is not being moved at all, And what you see is a snapshot of it being moved to simulate the movement, just like you would do while doing drag operation (while `LockWindowUpdate` is used). In that case you will not receive any standard window message notifications during the drag operation. IDE should have it's own notifications for that which I'm not familiar with.